# Bootstap Carousel Sizing

Tags: html, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a carousel using Bootstrap, I was using an example but it uses the entire window and any further div's are not shown, how do I fix this so the div's can be shown correctly, please?

Whilst researching I came across [this example](https://technext.github.io/drivin/index.html) but I can't figure out what they have done to fix this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="header_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Carousel Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid p-0 mb-5">
        <div id="header-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="licensed/p1.jpeg" alt="Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5">
                                    <h1 class="display-4 text-white mb-3 animated slideInDown">Let's Change The World With Humanity</h1>
                                    <p class="fs-5 text-white-50 mb-5 animated slideInDown">Aliqu diam amet diam et eos. Clita erat ipsum et lorem sed stet lorem sit clita duo justo erat amet</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3 animated slideInDown" href="">
                                        Learn More
                                        <div class="d-inline-flex btn-sm-square bg-white text-primary rounded-circle ms-2">
                                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="licensed/p2.jpeg" alt="Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5">
                                    <h1 class="display-4 text-white mb-3 animated slideInDown">Let's Save More Lifes With Our Helping Hand</h1>
                                    <p class="fs-5 text-white-50 mb-5 animated slideInDown">Aliqu diam amet diam et eos. Clita erat ipsum et lorem sed stet lorem sit clita duo justo erat amet</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3 animated slideInDown" href="">
                                        Learn More
                                        <div class="d-inline-flex btn-sm-square bg-white text-primary rounded-circle ms-2">
                                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel"
                data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel End -->

    <div">
        <p>Test #1</p>
    </div>
    <div">
        <p>Test #1</p>
    </div>
    <div">
        <p>Test #1</p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a typo after the end of carousel, ❌ `div"` -> ✅ `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it more responsive using `height: 100vh` which is equal to `vh-100` in bootstrap. (add this class with the width class of before  `w-100`)

and for making the image more responsive for all dimensions, just use `object-fit: cover`

> now is responsive for mobile and pc

also solve the div error  ❌`<div">` -> ✅`<div>`

```css
.carousel-item img {
  height: 100vh; /* vh-100 class */
  width: 100%; /* w-100 class */
  object-fit: cover; /* make image not stretch */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Carousel Start -->
  <div class="container-fluid p-0 mb-5">
    <div id="header-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/5000" alt="Image" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5">
                  <h1 class="display-4 text-white mb-3 animated slideInDown">
                    Let's Change The World With Humanity
                  </h1>
                  <p class="fs-5 text-white-50 mb-5 animated slideInDown">
                    Aliqu diam amet diam et eos. Clita erat ipsum et lorem sed stet lorem sit clita duo justo erat amet
                  </p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3 animated slideInDown" href="">
                      Learn More
                      <div
                        class="d-inline-flex btn-sm-square bg-white text-primary rounded-circle ms-2"
                      >
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/5000" alt="Image" />
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5">
                  <h1 class="display-4 text-white mb-3 animated slideInDown">
                    Let's Save More Lifes With Our Helping Hand
                  </h1>
                  <p class="fs-5 text-white-50 mb-5 animated slideInDown">
                    Aliqu diam amet diam et eos. Clita erat ipsum et lorem sed stet lorem sit clita duo justo erat amet
                  </p>
                  <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3 animated slideInDown" href="">
                      Learn More
                      <div
                        class="d-inline-flex btn-sm-square bg-white text-primary rounded-circle ms-2"
                      >
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel End -->

  <div>
    <p>Test #1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Test #1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Test #1</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:100%` and `height` for `carousel-item`

```css
 .carousel-item {
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-0 mb-5">
        <div id="header-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5">
                                    <h1 class="display-4 text-white mb-3 animated slideInDown">Let's Change The World With Humanity</h1>
                                    <p class="fs-5 text-white-50 mb-5 animated slideInDown">Aliqu diam amet diam et eos. Clita erat ipsum et lorem sed stet lorem sit clita duo justo erat amet</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3 animated slideInDown" href="">
                                        Learn More
                                        <div class="d-inline-flex btn-sm-square bg-white text-primary rounded-circle ms-2">
                                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-7 pt-5">
                                    <h1 class="display-4 text-white mb-3 animated slideInDown">Let's Save More Lifes With Our Helping Hand</h1>
                                    <p class="fs-5 text-white-50 mb-5 animated slideInDown">Aliqu diam amet diam et eos. Clita erat ipsum et lorem sed stet lorem sit clita duo justo erat amet</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-3 animated slideInDown" href="">
                                        Learn More
                                        <div class="d-inline-flex btn-sm-square bg-white text-primary rounded-circle ms-2">
                                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#header-carousel"
                data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel End -->

    <div>
        <p>Test #1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Test #1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Test #1</p>
    </div>
```